# "The met official has discarded possibility of the celcius breaching forty degree in coming days."

Tags: present-participles

I can not understand how the ing form has been used in the sentence with breach? Is it the shortening form?

> The met official has discarded possibility of the celcius **breaching** forty degree in coming days.

Comment: It's "Celsius", "forty degrees", and together "forty degrees Celsius". Did you write the sentence? If so please tell us that in your question.

Comment: Celsius is a temperature _scale_  -  we don't say 'the Celsius' to mean 'the temperature'. But it is quite normal to use the gerund (-ing) after 'the possibility of...'